# Connect Metamask in Mobile using Metamask application from any mobile web browser. How that possible? (Magento 2)

Tags: javascript, web3js, metamask, magento2.4

I am trying Metamask connect on mobile Metamask application. But i am not getting properly solutions for that. It's working fine in Web browser Metamask Extension.

The following code used for Web browser in Magento 2. But, not working with Mobile application. I am trying also using [detectEthereumProvider](https://docs.metamask.io/guide/ethereum-provider.html#ethereum-provider-api). But, it's also not working with mobile Metamask. I had also used [Provide window ethereum](https://docs.metamask.io/guide/mobile-best-practices.html#the-provider-window-ethereum). But, it's also not working.

```
require([
    'jquery',
    'Magento_Theme/js/view/messages',
    'mage/url',
    'web3'
    ], function($,messages,url,web3){
        let accounts;
        let contract;
        let contractAddress;

        const getData  = async () => {
            var web3 = new Web3(window.ethereum); /* initialize web3 object */
            const { ethereum } = window;

            var web3 = new Web3(window.ethereum);
            if (typeof window.ethereum !== 'undefined') {
                console.log('MetaMask is installed!');
            }
        }

        getData();
    }
);
```

I am also using [vanilla js using wallet connect with Web3model](https://github.com/Web3Modal/web3modal) but also not working. Because, It's said  Web3Modal NPM Package must be use for Web3model but it's possible on magento 2?